# What is a "delayed match-to-sample task"?

Tags: memory, terminology, methodology

[This question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/84/is-it-possible-to-measure-the-working-memory-of-a-non-human-animal) talked about how a "delayed match-to-sample task" can be used to measure an animal's [working memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory). What is a delayed match-to-sample task and how can it be used to measure working memory?

Comment: Short term memory and working memory(remember triangle study). Also ruling mind matching the sample long term memory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of task is generally used when studying short-term memory. Typically, a subject is presented with some stimuli, followed by a probe item after a varying delay; subjects is then asked to recall (information retrieval) if the probe item was presented before (information encoding). A famous example is [Sternberg experiment](http://web.uct.ac.za/depts/psychology/psy300/sternb.html).

Such tasks can rely on non-verbal material, which makes them good candidates for behavioral studies with animals, but see

> Paule MG, Bushnell PJ, Maurissen JP, Wenger GR, Buccafusco JJ,
>   Chelonis JJ, Elliott R. [Symposium overview: the use of delayed
>   matching-to-sample procedures in studies of short-term memory in
>   animals and humans](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9761587). Neurotoxicol Teratol. 1998
>   Sep-Oct;20(5):493-502.

Some on-line demonstration can be found on the CANTAB testing battery: [Delayed Matching to Sample (DMS)](http://www.camcog.com/cantab-tests-delayed-matching-to-sample.asp).